# Get id of selected element

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I'm trying to find a way to get the element id of the currently hovered element to show a popup box / tooltip. At the moment I'm using clientX / clientY to get coordinates but I would really like the popup to be centered over the element I'm hovering.

Is there some way to get this information, for example "who called show_tooltip" or similar to later get the coordinates of the element. Hope this makes sense.

In response to the comment below, this is what I'm currently using.

```
function show_tooltip(evt) {
    var x = evt.clientX -50;
    var y = evt.clientY -70;

    tooltip.setAttributeNS( null, "transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")" );
    tooltip.setAttributeNS( null, "opacity", "0.7" );
}
```

The problem  with this is that the mouse pointer is used for coordinates. While I can use `getElementById()` to get an element, I do not know *which* element that called the function.

Comment: can you show us an example of what you need in codes perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for:

```
<div onmouseover="show_tooltip(this)"/>
```

And you will get the element that fired the event in the js function.

Comment: Than you! This actually solved the problem. I'm using the `<g>` tag to group, but it worked as well. I added `this` as an argument to show_tooltip, then in the function, `getAttribute` to get the x and y coordinates of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have a look at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip ([demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/)). Thoose kinds of plugins have already been developed a lot of times. This one is just an example.

Comment: While this solves the problem, it does not answer the question. How can I get information on which element the mouse points at?

Comment: First, add a class to all your elements that could be hovered, for example `class="hoverable"`. Then, using jQuery, you can do something like `$(".hoverable").hover(function() {// ...})`

Answer (score 0):

[Event.target](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#interface-Event) (in your script `evt.target`) holds the target of the event (an element typically).